# Extract outlook settings from a non-bootable drive

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, data-recovery

I have a hard drive that won't boot any more, but I can mount it in Windows on another computer.

I'd like to extract all of the outlook settings from the dead drive so that I can replace the new hard drive's outlook settings with them.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mount the drive in another OS and the outlook data files mostly available in the documnets "Outlook Files" directory. Please refer the Microsoft link below for details regarding the outlook data file location based on installed OS.

https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Locating-the-Outlook-data-files-0996ece3-57c6-49bc-977b-0d1892e2aacc

If it was not configured in the default location check for below configuration files in hdd and try the directory as whole.

Outlook default configuration files are listed

```
ShowOutlook data files (.pst)

ShowOffline Folders file (.ost)

ShowPersonal Address Book (.pab)

ShowOffline Address Books (.oab)

ShowCommand bar and menu customizations (.dat)

ShowNavigation Pane settings (.xml)

ShowRegistered Microsoft Exchange extensions (.dat)

ShowOutlook contacts nicknames (.nk2)

ShowRules (.rwz)

ShowPrint styles (Outlprnt with no extension)

ShowSignatures (.rtf, .txt, .htm)

ShowStationary (.htm)

ShowCustom forms

ShowDictionary (.dic)

ShowTemplates (.oft)

ShowSend/Receive settings (.srs)

ShowMessage (.msg, .htm, .rtf)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:
Passcape Outlook Password Recovery**

Long answer:
First of all, we must difference between data, settings and passwords.

Data (emails, calendar...) is stored in .pst files, which are stored inside 
%userprofile%\appdata\local\microsoft\outlook*.pst
The autocompletion file is stored inside the file 
%userprofile%\appdata\local\microsoft\outlook\outlook.nk2

Account settings are stored in the registry, there are endless tools to extract them, or you could look manually.

Passwords are a more complicated thing: They are encrypted using your username and password as a base to generate the encryption code, so you need either to be loged in your user to be able to get it OR having and application that asks for your user's password before trying to obtain the password from another system.

ATM I only know one piece of soft which does so, **Passcape Outlook Password Recovery**, and it is not free. Its demo only shows you first 3 characters of the password and the whole server info. If any of you finds a free app I'd be glad to hear about it.